¿Cómo cerrar la aplicación WhatsApp Web y WhatsApp Desktop desde una macro en lenguaje VBA de Excel 2019?
Estoy tratando de terminar una macro para envíos masivos de WhatsApp's (sin saber lenguaje VBA, aunque sí programación) pero en el bucle me abre el navegador de WhatsApp por cada mensaje ¿Qué instrucción podría utilizar para cerrarlo? o mejor aún ¿habrá manera de hacer el llamado a WhatsApp una sola vez fuera del bucle y que haga todos los envíos y lo cierre al salir del bucle, cuando haya finalizado la macro?
Le estaré infinitamente agradecido a quién me pueda dar alguna pista o instrucción.
Estoy utilizando esta instrucción o línea de Código:
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%" & NumeroTelefono & "&text=" & Mensaje & "&app_absent=1&send=1", NewWindow:=False 

Esta instrucción está dentro del bucle con cada teléfono con las variables NumeroTelefono y Mensaje para el número telefónico y el mensaje individual (por si no queda tácito), obviamente abre una ventana del navegador por cada mensaje enviado. El asunto es que no sé como abrir el WhatsApp y luego pasarle los parámetros para que envíe los mensajes dentro de la Aplicación, si fuese posible hacerlo, o por lo menos cerrar la Ventana del navegador cada vez que se envíe el mensaje aunque no sea lo ideal, lo ideal sería que abriera WhatsApp Web, o mejor aun WhatsApp Desktop, una sola vez antes de entrar al bucle y que lo cerrara al salir de él.
Saludos desde Maracaibo, Venezuela.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Puedes utilizar Shell desde VBA para cerrar una tarea. Algo tipo wTask = Shell("c:\tuprograma\script.exe") lo iniciará y luego Shell "pskill " & wTask debería cerrarlo. En tu caso, posiblemente puedas cerrar el navegador.
